# How can I get the index of a property inside a JS object using the property key not the value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having a simple sample code as follows:

```
var sampleObj = [{prop1 : ""}, {prop2 : ""}, {propArr : [{key : "", value : ""}, {key : "", value : ""}]}];
```

This is a JSON Object that has some properties including a property that contains an array.

**My Question**

I need to use the JS method `indexOf()` to get the index of [propArr] using the key not the value.

for example
I need a way to implement this:

```
var index = sampleObj.indexOf(propArr);
```

Comment: *"This is a JSON Object"* JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Why do you *need* to use `indexOf`? What makes this restriction necessary?

Comment: Also, instead of an array of objects (which you confusingly call `sampleObj`), why not have an actual object with properties, and then they would be simple to access: `const obj = { prop1: 1, ... };` and then `console.log(obj.prop1)`. Then you don't need the index.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
var sampleObj=[{prop1:""},{prop2:""},{propArr:[{key:"",value:""},{key:"",value:""}]}];

const prop = "propArr"

const res = sampleObj.findIndex(e => Object.keys(e)[0] == prop)
console.log(res)
```

If you strictly need to use `indexOf`, you can map through the array to extract the first property of each object, then use `indexOf`:

```js
var sampleObj=[{prop1:""},{prop2:""},{propArr:[{key:"",value:""},{key:"",value:""}]}];

const prop = "propArr"

const res = sampleObj.map(e => Object.keys(e)[0]).indexOf(prop)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I need to use indexOf() not findIndex().